# How to change dropdown color in Firefox on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I've updated Firefox recently, and the background color of the suggestions dropdown menu has changed from white to dark-gray (desktop theme default).  How do I change it back to white?

I've created a userChrome.css file in the `chrome' subdirectory of the profile directory, with the following contents:

```
/*
 * Do not remove the @namespace line -- it's required for correct     functioning
 */
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* set default namespace to XUL */

menubar {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

But it didn't take noticable effect.

(I verified that userChrome.css works by setting the font size:

```
* {
font-size: 20pt !important
}
```

- and restarting Firefox.  The font size did change.)

If there's another way to change the background color of the menu, other than via userChrome.css, I'd be glad to hear it.

(Ubuntu 15.10 with default desktop environment.)

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: Default (Ambience).  Firefox has switched the way of rendering its menus to use GTK theme, hence the change in color.  But black on the browser's white is too high contrast, and site icons and (orange) links are visible poorly on this background.

Comment: Another option you could look at is to see how other themes look. Adwaita maybe installed on your system. Simply run `GTK_THEME=Adwaita firefox`. That will launch Firefox, and only Firefox, with the Adwaita theme.